# I have some issue when creating django project. I cannot create new project, whenever I run a command, I get error

Tags: python, django

```
C:\Users\Dnyane\Documents\file_1>py -m django --version
4.0.1

C:\Users\Dnyane\Documents\file_1>django-admin startproject project_1

CommandError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
   'C:\\Users\\Dnyane\\Documents\\file_1\\project_1'
```

Comment: Do you have correct permissions to the `file_1` directory?

Comment: From `C:\Users\Dnyane\Documents\file_1`, can you make a directory `test_dir` (on the command line)?

Comment: C:\Users\Dnyane\Documents\file_1>mkdir test_dir 
The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: That is strange. It almost appears as if you are still located in `C:\Users\Dnyane\Documents\file_1`, but that directory has been removed elsewhere, and you're seeing a "ghost" (by lack of a better word) of that directory. Try changing one directory higher, and then back again: `cd ..` then `cd file_1`, then `mkdir test_dir` again.

Comment: NB: I note that `file_1` is a confusing name for a directory.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this mkdir test_dir issue now everything is working properly by unblocking controlled folder access

thank you

Comment: Looks like he just want ask a question